# how to avoid click on parent by clicking on child?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class='titlewrap'>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br><br>
</title>
```

I want to separate right click on `titlewrap` vs `title`.

**js**

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.titlewrap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('titlewrap');
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', '.title', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('title');
});
```

Click on `title` gives double console result:
`titlewrap`
`title`

How to get only `title` by clicking on `title` and  keep `titlewrap` clicking on `titlewrap` (empty space below `title`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the event from bubbling up to the parent and triggering its event. You will still be able to trigger `titlewrap`'s event by right clicking on an area not covered by the `title` elements

```js
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.titlewrap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('titlewrap');
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', '.title', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('title');
});
```

```css
.titlewrap {
  padding:10px;
  border:black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding stopPropagation to the .title function like so

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.titlewrap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('titlewrap');
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', '.title', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('title');
});
```